# Can Firebase Extension use unofficial extensions?

Tags: firebase, firebase-extensions

I want to share a small cloud function to the user of my package. Is it possible to user firebase extensions for that?

I can easily create a structure that resembles this https://github.com/firebase/extensions/tree/next/storage-resize-images

Can other users install it from my repo instead of the Firebase one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase extensions currently doesn't support community-contributed functions.  Please [file a feature request with Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) to ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Following 18 October 2022 (Firebase Summit announcement)

Developers can create and manage their own extensions through the the Marketplace Alpha program.

Firebase Marketplace: https://extensions.dev/

Alpha: http://docs.google.com/forms/d/1XPmqbnakDa4ygqZBEaAIUFhQQ_CXOHlfV3IoHcgDPA8